# AS3 forlooping buttons and functions

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I'm learning Actionscript and I'm kind of stuck on for loop.

I have this code ,

```
movieClip.thumbnail1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK ,myBtn1);
function myBtn1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{

     var myMC:MC1 = new MC1();
     mcPlacement.addChild(myMC);
}

movieClip.thumbnail2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK ,myBtn2);
function myBtn2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{

     var myMC2:MC2 = new MC2();
     mcPlacement.addChild(myMC2);
}
```

and I am wondering, how do you use for loop to stack them up so that I can run over 10 buttons without having to type the long way, should I make use of arrays as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If movieClip contains only the thumbNails that you want to add event listeners for then you can do :

```
private function addEventListeners():void
{
    for(var i=0; i<movieClip.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var dp:DisplayObject = movieClip.getChildByIndex(i) as DisplayObject;
        dp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onThumbNailClicked);
    }
}

private function onThumbNailClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Clicked : "+e.target.name);

}
```

If you know the names of the thumbnails before hand you can create different movie clips inside the event handler and add them to mcPlacement.

```
private function onThumbNailClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mcs:Object = {
        "thumbNail1":MC1,
        "thumbNail2":MC2
    };
    trace("Clicked : "+e.target.name);
    var mc:MovieClip = new mcs[e.target.name]();
    mcPlacement.addChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I'll try to test this out. 
May i ask whether array can be applied to this?

Comment: You could potentially store the thumbs in an array and loop over them but I don't think it is necessary in this case since you can get to them using movieClip.getChildByIndex.